# Move subclass in other class when the subclass are = 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel slider, in desktop version I have 3 slide, now I want transform the 3 subslide in 2 subslide when screen size is < `769px`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="carousel">
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
</div>


<div class="carousel">
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
</div>


<div class="carousel">
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
</div>
```

The carousel is composed by 3 slide and for every slide have other 3 subslide.
Now in mobile I want for every carousel slide have 2 subslide so this is a code after:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
</div>


<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">image</div>
</div>
```

Now how make this with jQuery/Javascript?

**SECOND UPDATE WITH ALSO A TITLE :**

```
<div class="carousel">
<h2 class="titleslider">text</h2>

   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
</div>


<div class="carousel">
<h2 class="titleslider">text</h2>

   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
</div>


<div class="carousel">
<h2 class="titleslider">text</h2>

   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
   <div class="slide">image </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? *I want to... how?* is not a very nice question...

Comment: i don't have tried, not have idea how can implement this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do it with Javascript/jQuery, you could try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/mas68eL7/2/):

```js
var BREAKPOINT = 768;

var groupBy = function(blockClass, elementClass, count) {
    var $blocks = $('.' + blockClass);
    var $elements = $('.' + elementClass);
    var elementsCount = $elements.length;
    var blocksCount = Math.ceil(elementsCount / count);

    while ($blocks.length < blocksCount) {
        var $newBlock = $blocks.last().clone().insertAfter($blocks.last());
        $newBlock.children(':not(.titleslider)').remove();
        $blocks = $blocks.add($newBlock);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
        var j = Math.ceil((i + 1) / count) - 1;
        $blocks.eq(j).append($elements.eq(i));
    }
    
    while ($blocks.length > blocksCount) {
        $blocks.last().remove();
        $blocks.length--;
    }
};

var checkWindowSize = function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var width = $this.width();
    var lastWidth = $this.prop('lastWidth') || (BREAKPOINT + 1);

    if (lastWidth > BREAKPOINT && width <= BREAKPOINT) {
        groupBy('carousel', 'slide', 2);
    } else if (lastWidth <= BREAKPOINT && width > BREAKPOINT) {
        groupBy('carousel', 'slide', 3);
    }
    $this.prop('lastWidth', width);
};

var $window = $(window);
$window.on('resize', checkWindowSize);

if ($window.width() <= BREAKPOINT) {
    checkWindowSize();
}
```

```css
.carousel {
    background: yellow;
    min-width: 768px;
}

.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel">
    <h2 class="titleslider">text</h2>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel">
    <h2 class="titleslider">text</h2>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel">
    <h2 class="titleslider">text</h2>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
    <div class="slide">image</div>
</div>
```

But I **strongly recommend** you to try to use CSS for it. If you'll clarify your real case, maybe I could help you.

Comment: hi, thank you very much, it's  works, have some small question. 1)in <div <div class="carousel"> there is also a title H2 TAG, when move to 2 slide per slider the last slider not have a title, how add this h2 tag also the script ?(view a second update code). 2) if try in browser desktop to reduce the screen size the script is not dynamic and create a problem (show  5 slide), but if reload the page with screen reduced not have this problem , this problem is not present when open page in small screen page and after open full screen

Comment: @themich 1) Improved the answer, check it out. 2) Don't understand the problem, could you explain in more detail, please?

Comment: Thank you guys, have solved, with your second script has solved also the second problem.